# How to disable Tabris iOS client orientation?

Tags: ios, mobile

Is there a way to disable Tabris iOS client orientation? Meaning, I would like to fix the application orientation not change it when device orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no Tabris/Java API available ...yet - but it's planned.
To fix the App orientation, click on your Xcode App target, and select only the "Supported Device Orientations" (Options available there: Portrait, Upside Down, Landscape Left, Landscape Right)